Cómo arreglar productos sin imagen de portada en PrestaShop
En una tienda online PrestaShop he encontrado productos que tienen alguna imagen, pero ninguna está marcada como imagen de portada (cover), por lo que estos productos se listan en la tienda sin imagen.
Desconozco la causa de esta situación, pero quiero arreglarla.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para establecer una imagen de portada para todos esos productos que tienen alguna imagen registrada, pero ninguna está marcada como la imagen de portada?

Nota.- Esta solución es válida para un PrestaShop con la opción multitienda desactivada. La solución para multitienda hay que elaborarla un poco más.
Lo primero que vamos a hacer es identificar todos los productos que están en esa situación (tienen alguna imagen pero ninguna es la de portada), y vamos a guardar el Id. más bajo de sus imágenes, en una tabla temporal. Aplicamos esta consulta:
CREATE TABLE temp_image_id
AS SELECT MIN(id_image) AS id_image
FROM ps_image
WHERE id_product NOT IN (
    SELECT id_product FROM ps_image WHERE cover = 1
)
GROUP BY id_product;

El siguiente paso, es marcar cover (portada) para todas esas imágenes:
UPDATE ps_image SET cover = 1
WHERE id_image IN (
    SELECT id_image FROM temp_image_id
);

Como casi seguro al 100% estamos en un PrestaShop versión 1.5 ó superior, actualizamos cover en la tabla image_shop:
UPDATE ps_image_shop `is`
JOIN ps_image `i` ON `i`.id_image = `is`.id_image
SET `is`.cover = `i`.cover;

Finalmente, eliminamos la tabla temporal que usamos para saber a qué Id. de imágenes teníamos que marcarle cover:
DROP TABLE temp_image_id;

Ahora podemos comprobar si ya no queda ningún producto con alguna imagen pero sin imagen de portada:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_product)
FROM ps_image
WHERE id_product NOT IN (
    SELECT id_product FROM ps_image WHERE cover = 1
);

Deberíamos obtener cero.
Nota.- Usamos una tabla temporal, porque no podemos juntar todo en una sola consulta, bueno, sí podemos, pero esa consulta no funcionará, dará error porque intentará actualizar sobre un campo (cover) que es parte del filtro en la consulta. Eso no se puede hacer.
Nota.- Ten cuidado con el prefijo de las tablas en PrestaShop, en las consultas mostradas arriba se usa ps_, ya que es el prefijo por defecto. En tu instalación de PrestaShop puede ser otro distinto.
